# Scala app using Multiple Main Classes using SpringBootApplication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala, apache-spark

I'm working in an existing Scala app that gets executed in an EMR cluster that has its main application working. Then a new main class was added but never tested and that was my entrance.

So the structure of the application is something like this:

```
com.my.package
|_ some_subpackage_1
  |_ SomeUtilClass1.scala
|_ some_subpackage_2
  |_ SomeUtilClass2.scala
|_ some_subpackage_3
  |_ SomeUtilClass3.scala
|_ some_subpackage_4
  |_ SomeUtilClass4.scala
|_ FirstMainClass.scala
|_ SecondMainClass.scala
```

This main class launches like this:

```
bash -c "/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-java-options -Dspring.profiles.active=some-profile ...<some spark parameters>... --class com.my.package.firstMainClass s3://path/to/some/jar.jar ...<some app parameters>...
```

The FirstMainClass is structured something like this:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
class FirstMainClass

object FirstMainClass extends Serializable {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var sparkSession: SparkSession = null
        var applicationContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext = null

        try {
            sparkSession = SparkUtil.initSpark(args)
            applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(classOf[FirstMainClass], args: _ *)
            val factory: SomeUtilClass3 = applicationContext.getBean(classOf[SomeUtilClass3])
            val operation: SomeUtilCass2 = factory.doSomething(args)
            operation.doImportantThing()
        }
        catch {
            case e:Exception => LOGGER.error("Something failed", e)
                throw e
        }
        finally {
            sparkSession.close()
            applicationContext.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the class SomeUtilClass2 has an autowired SomeUtilClass1 variable. It works fine.

But then a second SecondMainClass was added following the same pattern as above for launch, but just changing...

```
    applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(classOf[SecondMainClass], args: _ *)
    val factory: SomeUtilClass3 = applicationContext.getBean(classOf[SomeUtilClass3])
    val operation: SomeUtilClass4 = factory.doSomething(args)
```

SomeUtilClass4 has an autowired SomeUtilClass1 variable.

I get during application context load the following error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'SomeUtilClass1';
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.my.package.config.some_subpackage_1.SomeUtilClass1'

I then later updated the SecondMainClass context load code to:

```
val application = new SpringApplication(classOf[SecondMainClass], classOf[SomeUtilClass1], classOf[SomeUtilClass2], ...)
application.run(args: _*)
```

Since "scanBasePackageClasses" in the SpringBootApplication annotation didn't seem to work. And that seems to help as with every attempt, I get a different "bean not found" error, but since the application is quite large, I don't think it's a good approach to add a list of dozens of classes... Any idea? Any way to fix this approach?